# How can I add my own custom filters in the Camera API?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am currently working with the Camera API and creating my own custom camera. I wish to add my own custom filters just like many famous camera apps, i.e. candy camera b16.

Currently, I am able to set builtin filters like `Effect_MONO EFFECT_NEGATIVE` using the `setCameraEffect` parameter.

My question is how can I add my own custom filters?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most performant option for this, is to bind the camera frame to a opengl es texture and then do your own filter as a GLSL shader.

There are libraries that do all of this for you like [this one](https://github.com/nekocode/CameraFilter).

Comment: i have tried this library. it has limited set of filter, tho i believe i can make more filters if i know opengl but opengl has never been my subject. Thanks anyway. @Bernd